# Peano's question about how to define a definition

Tags: definition

In Wikipedia’s [Peano entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giuseppe_Peano) I find the following quote:

> [In] the First International Conference of Philosophy [Peano]
> presented a paper which posed the question of correctly formed
> definitions in mathematics, i.e. "how do you define a definition?".
> This became one of Peano's main philosophical interests for the rest
> of his life.

Did Peano answer the question he posed? Where can I find more information about the subject?

Comment: Section 8 of the 1908 edition of the Formulario discusses definitions in mathematics. This article also discuss's Peano idea on definitions: [Kennedy. *Hist. Math.* **1** (1974) 387–408](https://doi.org/10.1016/0315-0860(74)90031-7)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks. This was helpful. I'm also trying to understand why Peano, first started the series of natural numbers with 1 then in 1898 he decided to start with zero. Kennedy's paper mentions this but does not give a reason why. Any idea why Peano swiitched to 0? Is this more math question than a history of math question, I wasn't sure.

Comment: I don't know why. From a math point of view, I don't know that it is important. I tend to think the choice whether to include zero in the natural numbers is a matter of convenience and depends on the context in which they are used. For instance, E. Landau started with one in *Foundations of Analysis* (1930), which makes some inequalities ($x+y>x$) and (positive) fractions of natural numbers easier to deal with (Ch. 2). I don't know why Landau made this choice, though. However, it is evidence that Peano's switch to zero did not prevent others from choosing one as the starting number afterwards.